Help me identify this 4 pin IC
Can anyone help me identify the component circled in the picture below?
The marking says 9c304.


It's probably a STM L79L05 negative voltage regulator. The datasheet doesn't specify the markings, but if we look a different pictures, ...

(Source: lcsc.com)

(Source: aliexpress.com)
it looks like 9C is the product code and the following three numbers are a traceability code. Maybe a lot number or date code.

Confirmed - negative 5V LDO. Measured on the same chinese switching PS display board.
